# Confused about wildcard generic types in Java

Tags: java, generics

I'm a beginner in Java and I'm having a hard time understanding the wildcard generic types. Can anyone help me understand why the following two lines are incorrect?

```
LinkedList<? extends List> list1 = new LinkedList<ArrayList>();
LinkedList<? super List> list2 = new LinkedList<Collection>();
```

When I tried to compile them, I got the following error message:

```
Test.java:13: error: incompatible types: LinkedList<ArrayList> cannot be converted to LinkedList<? extends List>
    LinkedList<? extends List> list1 = new LinkedList<ArrayList>();
                                       ^
Test.java:14: error: incompatible types: LinkedList<Collection> cannot be converted to LinkedList<? super List>
    LinkedList<? super List> list2 = new LinkedList<Collection>();
                                     ^
2 errors
```

Comment: What version of java? It compiles fine in Java 1.8.0_91. I do get warnings in Eclipse though, since `List`, `ArrayList`, and `Collection` are *raw* types, i.e. they are missing their generic type parameters. E.g. it should be something like `LinkedList<? extends List<String>> list1 = new LinkedList<ArrayList<String>>()`

Comment: But it's strange that `LinkedList<? super List> list3 = new LinkedList<List>();` works fine.

Comment: I find it even stranger that you don't say which version of Java you are having trouble with, but maybe you're not really looking for help?

Comment: So sorry that I forgot to say that my version is the same as yours.

Comment: what's the compiler version in eclipse? using JDK8 or just JRE8 ?

Comment: You haven't shown your imports. Maybe you are importing in such a way that `List` is not `java.util.List`, e.g. it could be `java.awt.List`, or a custom class called `List` in the same package (classes in the same package have higher priority than imports of the form `import java.util.*;`). Same with `ArrayList` and `Collection`.

Answer (score -3):

if we break down the first, it might make a bit more sense:

```
LinkedList<? extends List> list1
```

you declare list1 to be a LinkedList whose element type can be compatable with any subclass of List.

```
list1 = new LinkedList<ArrayList>();
```

you then try to instantiate list1 as a LinkedList whose element type is restricted to ArrayList. That's probably why the compiler complains about the incompatable types for that first line. You need to make sure the generic type for the declaration and instantiation of List1 are compatable, <s>like so:</s>

```
LinkedList<? extends List> list1 = new LinkedList<? extends List>();
```

I was mistaken. The compiler throws an error for the above line. This line does work though and is probably what you want:

```
LinkedList<List> list1 = new LinkedList<List>();
```

[check out example code here](http://ideone.com/8r1eiU)

As of java 7, you can use the diamond operator to infer the generic type in the instantiation part:

```
list1 = new LinkedList<>();
```

Comment: But I'm still confused why the compiler thinks it's incompatable since ArrayList is a subclass of List.

Comment: @legoer the generic type is declared to be compatable with ANY subclass of List. wheras in the instantiation the generic type can ONLY be of type ArrayList. Those two generic parameters aren't completely compatable.

Comment: let me put it this way, `List list1 = new ArrayList();` is legal because ArrayList is a List. however, in your case, `LinkedList<? extends List>` is not the same as `LinkedList< ArrayList>` because the generic types do not allow the same kinds of types

Comment: `LinkedList<? extends List>` can hold any element whose type is a subclass of List, ie ArrayList, LinkedList, etc. However, `LinkedList<ArrayList>` can only hold ArrayLists, which does not include other sublcasses of List.

Comment: Have you tried compiling this? `new LinkedList<? extends List>()` is a compile time error, since you cannot construct a parameterized type with a wildcard type for its type parameter.

Comment: @DanielPryden you're right. i fixed it and gave working code